# Why will my tree struct not assign its variable?

Tags: c, xcode, struct, tree, variable-assignment

I am making my very first parser and have drawn up a parser that should work but when I tested whether the parser was working correctly I discovered that everything was working the right way except the tree struct's variables are not getting their assignment. The right and left nodes are getting generated but the sym value within the node is not being assigned. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h> // isalpha, etc.

struct node{
    int val;
    char sym;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

struct look_up_table{
    char equation[20];
    char literal[20];
    char symbols[20];
    int number[20];
    int symbolsx[20];
    int symbolsy[20];
    char abstractsf[20];
    int abstractx[20];
    int abstracty[20];
};

struct look_up_table *buildtable(){
    struct look_up_table* name =(struct look_up_table*)malloc(sizeof(struct look_up_table));
    return name;
};

struct node *buildtree(){
    struct node* name=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    return name;
}

void settable(struct look_up_table *table){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<20;i++){
        table->equation[i]='\0';
        table->literal[i]='\0';
        table->symbols[i]='0';
        table->number[i]='\0';
        table->symbolsx[i]='\0';
        table->symbolsy[i]='\0';
        table->abstractsf[i]='\0';
    }
}
void handle(struct look_up_table * table){
    _Bool pattern = 1;
    int i;
    for(i=0;table->equation[i]!='\0';i++){
        if (pattern){
            if (isalpha(table->equation[i]))
                table->literal[i]='l';
            else if (isdigit(table->equation[i]))
                table->literal[i]='i';
            else
                table->literal[i]=table->equation[i];
        }
    }
}

void parse1(struct look_up_table *table,int i, int p){
    char dec[20];
    if (table->literal[i]!='\0'){
        switch(table->literal[i]){
        case 'i':
            for (table->symbolsx[i]=i; table->literal[i]=='i'; i++)
                dec[p]=table->equation[i];
            --i;
            table->symbolsy[i]=p;
            table->symbols[p]='i';
            table->number[p++]=atoi(dec);
            break;
        case '*': table->symbols[p++]='*';  break;
        case '/': table->symbols[p++]='/';  break;
        case '+': table->symbols[p++]='+';  break;
        case '-': table->symbols[p++]='-';  break;
        case '(': table->symbols[p++]='(';  break;
        case ')': table->symbols[p++]=')';  break;
        case '^': table->symbols[p++]='^';  break;
        case 'l': table->symbols[p]='l';
                  table->symbolsx[p++]=i;
                  break;
        default:  // TODO: error handling
                  break;
        }
        if (table->literal[i]!='\0')
            parse1(table, ++i, p);
    }
}

void treebuild(struct look_up_table table, struct node root,int i, int b, int e){
    while (table.symbols[i]!='\0'){
        if(table.symbols[i]=='('){
            int count=1;
            while(table.symbols[++i]!=')'&& count>0){
                if (table.symbols[i]==')')
                    count--;
                if(table.symbols[i]=='(')
                    count++;
            }
        }
        if (table.symbols[i]=='+'||table.symbols[i]=='-'){
            switch (table.literal[i]) {
            case '+':
                root.sym='+';
                treebuild(table, *root.left, b,b,i-1);
                treebuild(table, *root.right, i+1, i+1,e);
                break;
            case '-':
                root.sym='-';
                treebuild(table, *root.left, b,b,i-1);
                treebuild(table, *root.right, i+1, i+1,e);
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        i=b;
        while (table.symbols[i]!='\0'){
            switch (table.symbols[i]){
            case 'i':
                if (table.symbols[++i]=='\0'){
                    root.sym='i';
                    root.val=table.number[--i];
                    return;
                }
                switch(table.symbols[i]){
                case '(':
                    root.sym='*';
                    root.left->val=table.number[table.symbolsx[i-1]];
                    treebuild(table, *root.right,i , i, e);
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    root.sym='*';
                    root.left=buildtree();
                    root.left->val=table.number[table.symbolsx[i-1]];
                    root.right=buildtree();
                    treebuild(table, *root.right,i , i, e);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    root.sym='*';
                    root.left->val=table.number[table.symbolsx[i-1]];
                    treebuild(table, *root.right, i+1, i+1, e);
                    break;
                case'/':
                    root.sym='/';
                    root.left->val=table.number[table.symbolsx[i-1]];
                    treebuild(table, *root.right, i+1, i+1, e);
                    break;
                case'^':
                    root.sym='^';
                    root.left->val=table.number[table.symbolsx[i-1]];
                    treebuild(table, *root.right, i+1, i+1, e);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    struct look_up_table* table= buildtable();
    settable(table);
    gets(table->equation);
    handle(table);
    int i=0;
    int p=0;
    parse1(table, i, p);
    i=0;
    int t=0;
    struct node* root= buildtree();
    int m;
    for(m=0;table->symbols[m]!='0';m++){

    }
    treebuild(*table, *root, i, i, m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Missing semi-colon after the buildtree struct

Comment: I am away from my computer with the compiler but I'll check it in a little bit

Comment: I tried to make your code more readable (and shorter!). I didn't test it though, so I hope I didn't break it ... further. :)

Comment: @JWarren `buildtree` is not a struct. It's a function.

Comment: When I put the semi colon on the buildtree function it did not allow the variable to be assigned

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your node in the `buildtree` function